# How to know if password is set for current WIFI network?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Is there a way to know if a password was required to connect to the current WIFI network ? Note that I only would like to know if there is a password, and not what the password actually was.

I looked into `WifiConfiguration`, `WifiNetwork` and `WifiInfo`, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The [`capabilities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities) field of `ScanResult` can be helpful, but not exactly directly.  It will tell you if the access point speaks WPA/WPA2/WEP which will require a password. If none of those are present, then it is likely password free.

For reference, my AP is listed as "[ESS]" when in an "open" configuration.  Some nearby APs have `[WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][ESS]` and `[WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][ESS]` as capabilities.